# Haskell type inference about monad

Tags: haskell, types, monads

How can I do the type inference from the type of `Control.Monad.liftM not` to `Control.Monad.liftM not id`?

```
(Control.Monad.liftM not) :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool

(Control.Monad.liftM not id) :: Bool -> Bool
```

Comment: The trick is realizing that in the 2nd case, the `m` is being instantiated to a concrete type - namely to the function monad `((->) x`. The inference proceeds fairly simply: the argument to `liftM not` has type `m Bool` and `id :: a -> a`, so `a -> a ~ m Bool`, from which you have `m ~ ((->) a), a ~ Bool`.

Answer (score 4):

```
liftM not    :: Monad m =>                 m Bool -> m Bool
id           ::                            a -> a
liftM not id :: (Monad m, m ~ ((->) a), a ~ Bool) => m Bool
           {- therefore -}                           Bool -> Bool
```